# grails 2.0 - formatDate using fieldValue, is this a bug in Grails 2.0?

Tags: grails, taglib, grails-2.0

In my Grails 2.0 the following GSP code works:

```
 <g:formatDate date="${merchantTrans.dateCreated}" />
```

But the code

```
 <g:formatDate date="${fieldValue(bean: merchantTrans, field: 'dateCreated')}" />
```

causes the following error:

Stacktrace follows: Message: Unknown class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer

I tried different combos of single and double quotes but got the same error. This code worked in Grails 1.3.7, so ?  There, I actually got away using double quotes on `dateCreated` as well as on date="...".

If you have a moment, can you please test a dateCreated field in one of your domain objects to see if you get the same thing.  Perhaps I have some other update-to-Grails 2.0 problem that I'm unaware of?

In case it matters, I iterate over the `merchantTrans` objects as so:

```
<g:each in="${merchantTransactionInstanceList}" status="i" var="merchantTrans">
```

Thanks, Ray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that's no bug. The `fieldValue` tag converts the passed property to a `String` and also does a HTML encoding. This means the response cannot be formatted as a `Date` simply because its a `String`.

Only your first snippet passes the raw date:

```
<g:formatDate date="${merchantTrans.dateCreated}" />
```

It it worked prior Grails 2.0 this may have been a defect.